# How do I split a video to 4 subpicture and serve them with rtsp?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

I have one video, and need to split it to 4 videos, 2 x 2 by frame, then serve them with rtsp,

```
rtsp://192.168.1.100/left-top
rtsp://192.168.1.100/right-top
rtsp://192.168.1.100/left-bottom
rtsp://192.168.1.100/right-bottom
```

better keep original timestamps

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic example using the [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) filter:

```
ffmpeg -re -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]crop=iw/2:ih/2:0:0[left-top];[0:v]crop=iw/2:ih/2:ow:0[right-top];[0:v]crop=iw/2:ih/2:0:oh[left-bottom];[0:v]crop=iw/2:ih/2:ow:oh[right-bottom]" -map "[left-top]" rtsp://192.168.1.100/left-top -map "[right-top]" rtsp://192.168.1.100/right-top -map "[left-bottom]" rtsp://192.168.1.100/left-bottom -map "[right-bottom]" rtsp://192.168.1.100/right-bottom
```

Remove `-re` if using a live input.